# Problems converting an object into JSON in php

Tags: php, json

I need to convert an object into JSON using a php script.

I wrote this code in a loop cycle:

```
$zaino->rows[$num_oggetti]->item = $oggetto;
$zaino->rows[$num_oggetti]->amount = $num;
```

After the loop cycle I convert the object into json: `json_encode($zaino);`

This is what I get:

```
{"rows":{"1":{"item":"Soffio di Morte","amount":"1"},"2":{"item":"Pietra Anima di Ferro","amount":"11"},"3":{"item":"Pietra Anima di Legno","amount":"12"}}
```

But I need something like:

```
{"rows":[{"item":"Soffio di Morte","amount":"1"},{"item":"Pietra Anima di Ferro","amount":"11"},{"item":"Pietra Anima di Legno","amount":"12"}]}
```

without numbers between `""`, so that I can easily get the values using for example `$zaino->rows[1]->item` after calling a `json_decode`. How can I do it?

Comment: $zaino->rows[] = ('item'=>$item, 'amount'=>$num);

Comment: edited: $zaino->rows[] = array('item'=>$item, 'amount'=>$num);

Comment: Thank you man! This solved my problem!

Comment: couldn't you marked my comment as solved or just arrow up ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$num_oggetti` is a string value, not a number (yes, numeric, but not a number). This tells PHP that you are setting a key instead of an index.

If you do not need the actual index you could do something like:

```
$zaino->rows[] = [
  'item'   => $oggetto,
  'amount' => $num
];
```

This way you leave the index generation entirely up to PHP and you'll get the json output you want.